# Determining distance between point feature and nearest point feature in same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, proximity

I have one layer which contains school locations. What I want to do is find the nearest distance between these point features. Keep in mind it's one layer.

Any solution?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [generate near table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) tool and ensure your point layer is both the input features and near features. Untick Find only closest feature and set maximum number of matches to 1.